# Ng-Map show me multiple instance of the map. Why?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ng-map

[image]

I got this bug. And I don't know from where it comes out.
I spent a lot of time on check the code, but while in development everything is correct, on production this comes out.

No differences there are basically on the environment.

Maybe some who worked with Ng-Map recognize somewhat. It will be very useful. I am totally freaking out.

What I do on this map?

```
<div>


 <ng-map
                                    center="{{ vm.center || 'Roma, Italia' }}"
                                    zoom="7"
                                    pan-control="true"
                                    map-type-control="true"
                                    map-type-control-options="{style:'DROPDOWN_MENU'}"
                                    zoom-control="true"
                                    zoom-control-options="{style:'SMALL'}"
                                    default-style="true">

                                <marker ng-repeat="user in vm.data.users" id="{{user._id}}" position="{{user.addressOffice}}" on-click="vm.showDetail(user)"></marker> 

                                <info-window id="foo-iw">
                                        Some text
                                </info-window>

                                </ng-map>

                                </div>
```

The Json I retrieved has this structure (I omitted some parts, obviously):

```
[{"_id":"581a552ca38813684fcb414f","lastname":"Canto","firstname":"Giuseppe","addressOffice":"Via Cerquitello, 03022 Colle Campano-Scrima FR, Italia","locationOffice":[13.463063899999952,41.62412599999999]]
```

One More thing:
If I zoom out I got this:
[image]

Comment: Can you post the JSON that is being used?  Maybe there's something in the JSON causing a problem with the `<marker ng-repeat>`.

Comment: Add it. What do you think?

Comment: I don't see anything obvious.  What I would suggest is using the developer console of Chrome or Firefox (using the "Inspect Element" feature) to check the HTML that is being generated by Angular to create the DOM.  When you see how Angular (and/or ng-Map) is creating the HTML elements, maybe you will discover the problem.